# Problemas al traer datos a un formulario de editar

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Realizo un formulario en donde quiero ***modificar algunos datos que están insertados en mi BD***, pero *tengo problema con dos campos ya que no me los trae en mi formulario es decir, al darle click al icono de editar me rellena el formulario con los datos que están guardados en mi BD y que pertenecen a ese registro*, pero tengo dos campos que no me muestra los datos correspondientes  son **idctg_turno** y **fecha_nac**,en mi BD tengo llaves foráneas.

**Estructura de mi tabla trabajador**

```
id_Control   Primaria      int(10)  
nombre                     varchar(30)
ap_paterno                 varchar(30)
ap_materno                 varchar(30)
NSS                        varchar(30)
CURP                       varchar(30)
RFC                        varchar(30)
fecha_nac                  date
id_area        Índice      int(10)
idctg_turno    Índice      int(10)
idctg_empresa  Índice      int(10)
id_nomina      Índice      int(11)
id_activo      Índice      int(11)
```

Este es mi código de mi formulario editar

```html
<?php
    $puesto =mysqli_query($con, "select * from puesto");
    $area =mysqli_query($con, "select * from area");
    $turno =mysqli_query($con, "select * from ctg_turno");
    $empresa =mysqli_query($con, "select * from empresa");
    $nomina =mysqli_query($con, "select * from nomina");
 $activo =mysqli_query($con, "select * from activo");
?>



<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Fecha Nacimiento<span class="required">*</span></label>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
<input type="date" name="fecha_nac" class="form-control" placeholder="fecha_nac" id="mod_fecha_nac" required>
</div>
  </div>
                        
                        
                        
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Turno
 </label>
 <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
 <select class="form-control" name="idctg_turno" required id="mod_idctg_turno">
 <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
 <?php foreach($turno as $p):?>
 <option value="<?php echo $p['idctg_turno']; ?>"><?php echo $p['descripcion']; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Aquí es donde llamo a los datos por "modal"

```html
    function obtener_datos(id_Control){
  
        var description = $("#description"+id_Control).val();
        var nombre = $("#nombre"+id_Control).val();
  var ap_paterno = $("#ap_paterno"+id_Control).val();
  var ap_materno = $("#ap_materno"+id_Control).val();
  var NSS = $("#NSS"+id_Control).val();
  var CURP = $("#CURP"+id_Control).val();
  var RFC = $("#RFC"+id_Control).val();
  var fecha_nac = $("#fecha_nac"+id_Control).val();
  var id_puesto = $("#id_puesto"+id_Control).val();
  var id_area = $("#id_area"+id_Control).val();
  var idctg_turno = $("#idctg_turno"+id_Control).val();
  var idctg_empresa = $("#idctg_empresa"+id_Control).val();
  var id_nomina = $("#id_nomina"+id_Control).val();
  var id_activo = $("#id_activo"+id_Control).val();

            $("#mod_id_Control").val(id_Control);
            $("#mod_nombre").val(nombre);
            $("#mod_ap_paterno").val(ap_paterno);
            $("#mod_ap_materno").val(ap_materno);
            $("#mod_NSS").val(NSS);
   $("#mod_CURP").val(NSS);
            $("#mod_RFC").val(RFC);
            $("#mod_fecha_nac").val(fecha_nac);
            $("#mod_id_puesto").val(id_puesto);
   $("#mod_id_area").val(id_area);
   $("#mod_idctg_turno").val(idctg_turno);
   $("#mod_idctg_empresa").val(idctg_empresa);
   $("#mod_id_nomina").val(id_nomina);
   $("#mod_id_activo").val(id_activo);
        }
```

**Estructura tabla ctg_turno**

```
idctg_turno           PrimariaÍndice    int(10)
descripcion            varchar(20)
Jornada                int(11)
```

Comment: Estas mostrando la estructura de tu tabla "trabajador", sin embargo en tus selecciones o consultas no veo que traigas esos datos de dicha tabla..en otras palabras no estas consultando esa tabla..

Comment: Buen día, en esta query: $turno =mysqli_query($con, "select * from ctg_turno"); Estas colocando el nombre de la tabla como `ctg_turno` y tu mencionas que tu tabla se llama `trabajador`, tal vez estás consultado una tabla que no existe o que no contiene los campos que buscas.

Comment: @Tegito123 Lo siento olvide colocar el codigo donde llamo a mis campos lo edito

Comment: Buenos dias, de echo hago un select en donde llamo todas las tablas y en esta linea <?php foreach($turno as $p):?> es donde coloco a que tabla corresponde

Comment: @Carmen Buenos dias, en mi BD si tengo almacenadas fechas, pero no se que estoy haciendo mal que no traigo esa información para editarla en mi formulario

Comment: @Carlos en el caso de la fecha puede ser una cuestión de diferencia de formatos, comprueba que el formato de salida de tu base de datos es el mismo que necesitas para que el valor se vea en uyn campo date, sino traélo formateado de la base de datatos con DATE_FORMAT.

Comment: En el caso del select haz un var_dump($turno) para comprobar qué trae la variable y ver que la forma de recorrer los datos de array es correcta, ya que no sabemos la estructura de la tabla de origen

Comment: @carmen realice el var_dump y no me toma ningun valor, de echo tengo varios campos y los mando a llamar de la mismo forma y este es uno de los que no muestra, si despliego mi select me aparecen los valores pero no me trae el que corresponde a ese registro. Ya coloque la estructura de la tabla origen

Comment: Prueba a quitar selected de la primera opción <option value="">-- Selecciona --</option>

Comment: @Carmen realizando lo queme indicas ya no aparece el select pero de igual manera no me da el valor por defaul tengo que deslizar mi select para seleccionar el valor

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79796/discussion-between-carlos-and-carmen).